# Merge video with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have tried this command:
`ffmpeg -i 'concat:10.mov|11.mov' -codec copy out.mov`
The output file out.mov only shows whats in the first movie (10.mov).

Been googling for several hours and tried lots of things but nothing works. I want this done without re-encoding the files. Just merge with the same codec 
`ffmpeg version 3.2.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.2.4 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --disable-lzma --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7ff678802600] Found duplicated MOOV Atom. Skipped it
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'concat:10.mov|11.mov':
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2017-03-17T12:15:22.000000Z
    major_brand     : qt

    minor_version   : 537134592
    compatible_brands: qt

  Duration: 00:00:29.96, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 140810 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: prores (apcn / 0x6E637061), yuv422p10le, 1280x720, 116735 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 50 fps, 50 tbr, 5k tbn, 5k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Telestream Inc. Telestream Media Framework - Local 99.99.999999
      encoder         : Apple ProRes 422
Output #0, mov, to 'out.mov':
  Metadata:
    compatible_brands: qt

    major_brand     : qt

    minor_version   : 537134592
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: prores (apcn / 0x6E637061), yuv422p10le, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 116735 kb/s, 50 fps, 50 tbr, 10k tbn, 5k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Telestream Inc. Telestream Media Framework - Local 99.99.999999
      encoder         : Apple ProRes 422
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 1498 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=  426938kB time=00:00:29.94 bitrate=116815.8kbits/s speed=50.8x

video:426930kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.001997%`

Any ideas? Would make my life very much easier if I got this to work :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Quicktime files have an index, so can't be joined using a dumb operation such as the concat protocol.

The concat demuxer is required for such formats:

**#1** Create a text file.

```
file '10.mov'
file '11.mov'
```

**#2** Join them

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -c copy merged.mov
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfect. All i have to do now is to figure out a way to create the .txt-file in applescript. Bur that's another headache :D

Comment: Well the headache is here now :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42868682/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-to-shell-script

Comment: If you get "Unsafe file name" errors, add the flag `-safe 0` to the ffmpeg command.

Answer (score 1):

```
If you want to merge several video files, you can use these command.

- concat two video files.
ffmpeg -f concat -i 1.mp4 -1 2.mp4 -codec copy out.mp4

- concat multiple video files.
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i 3.mpt -vcodec copy -acodec copy out.mp4

And then you can cut a video file with ffmpeg.
ffmpeg -i 1,mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:01:20 -t 00:06:10.325 out.mp4
'-ss' : start_time
'-to' : end_time,
'-t' : duration_time;
```

Comment: What if you want to keep the subtitles?