# FFmpeg - Concatenate videos with not know format

Tags: shell, ffmpeg, concatenation

I am developing an application.
People upload videos from their mobile, from other places.

Using a CMS in PHP (it is the language with which the application is developed) I need to generate a unique video with these partial uploads.

Through FFmpeg I am doing tests, from the command line:

```
ffmpeg -i concat:IMG_1916.mp4\|IMG_1917.mp4 -c copy videoLoop.mp4
```

This code when I run it says:

```
ffmpeg version 3.2.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers

built with Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)

configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.2.4 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --disable-lzma --enable-vda
    libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
    libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
    libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
    libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
    libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
    libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
    libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
    libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
    libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100

[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f8515000000] Found duplicated MOOV Atom. Skipped it Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'concat:IMG_1916.mp4|IMG_1917.mp4':
Metadata:

    encoder         : Lavf57.66.102
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41

Duration: 00:00:04.27, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 26792 kb/s

    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 11978 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)

Metadata:

    handler_name    : VideoHandler

Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 120 kb/s (default)
Metadata:

    handler_name    : SoundHandler

Output #0, mp4, to 'videoLoop.mp4':

Metadata:

    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1920x1080, q=2-31, 11978 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 30k tbc (default)

Metadata:

    handler_name    : VideoHandler

Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, mono, 120 kb/s (default)
Metadata:

    handler_name    : SoundHandler

Stream mapping:

    Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
    Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)

Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  127 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    6264kB time=00:00:04.22 bitrate=12142.8kbits/s speed= 376x    
video:6196kB audio:63kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.076698%
```

This execution generates a video, but not concatenated with the 2 specified, only with the first one.

Why not join the 2?

The videos to upload, will be of very different formats so I can not define codec.

Comment: Where did you get the documentation indicating that syntax (with a literal pipe)? I don't see anything of the sort indicated at https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#differentcodec

Comment: ...I mean, yes, there's the concat protocol, but that's **explicitly** documented for use only when your codecs match; you can't use it here.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard, ...given as the accepted answer there depends on the codecs matching, which is explicitly contrary to a given requirement here, I'm not certain that the currently-flagged duplicate (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42859528/merge-video-with-ffmpeg) is ideal.

Answer (score 4):

You will have to make all inputs similar before concatenation, then use the [concat filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat). A rough example (you will of course have to customize it to your needs):

```
ffmpeg -i input0 -i input1 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]fps=25,scale=1280:720,format=yuv420p,setsar=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; \
 [1:v]fps=25,scale=1280:720,format=yuv420p,setsar=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; \
 [0:a]aformat=channel_layouts=stereo:sample_rates=44100,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0]; \
 [1:a]aformat=channel_layouts=stereo:sample_rates=44100,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1]; \
 [v0][a0][v1][a1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" \
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this adaptation of code, i can generate a video with two sources.

```
ffmpeg -i IMG_1916.mp4 -i IMG_1917.mp4 \
-filter_complex \
"[0:v:0] [0:a:0] \
[1:v:0] [1:a:0] \
concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" \
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" videoLoop.mp4
```

I'm not sure if I can concatenate any video format, from any device of any source / format with this code.

Comment: This will fail if the inputs don't match width, height, and aspect ratio. Also, because the concat filter will automatically choose some "common" parameters, such as audio sample rate, you may get unexpected results depending on the "common" parameters of the inputs. In other words, if you want a stereo output, and your inputs are mono, then concat will make a mono output unless you tell it not to (such as in my answer).

Comment: Ok, i use your answer, adapted to my settings and works fine!!!

Thanks!!!